# Python float to ratio

Tags: python, python-3.x, floating-point, fractions

I try to represent a floating point number as a ratio of two integers, but for some reason the integers that I get are quite different from what I would expect to see. Can somebody explain this?

```
>>> value = 3.2
>>> ratios = value.as_integer_ratio()
>>> ratios
(3602879701896397, 1125899906842624)
>>> ratios[0] / ratios[1]
3.2
```

I would say that `(32, 10)` or `(16, 5)` are much better solutions to the problem. What's strange is that if I try to do the same for number like 2.5, the answer is exactly what I would expect

```
>>> value = 2.5
>>> value.as_integer_ratio()
(5, 2)
```

Comment: What were you expecting?

Comment: `16 / 5`? Why not `32 / 10`?

Comment: `(16, 5)` for example. But I understand why I get so big numbers

Comment: 16 / 5 is a most simplified form

Comment: Possible duplicates: every question ever asked about floating point math.

Comment: @qwertynl: Because `16 / 5` is simplified to a prime number divisor?

Comment: Ah.. yes i understand the question now. I thought you were asking why dividing the ratios gives you that result. That, that's because `3.2` is not exactly `3.2`, as jon pointed out in his answer.

Comment: I guess this may help. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2100490/floating-point-inaccuracy-examples .

Comment: Enter 3.2 in a [IEEE 754 converter](https://www.h-schmidt.net/FloatConverter/IEEE754.html) and see what is stored instead. Then enter 32 or 2.5.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Use the [`fractions` module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/fractions.html) to simplify fractions:

```
>>> from fractions import Fraction
>>> Fraction(3.2)
Fraction(3602879701896397, 1125899906842624)
>>> Fraction(3.2).limit_denominator()
Fraction(16, 5)
```

From the [`Fraction.limit_denominator()` function](http://docs.python.org/2/library/fractions.html#fractions.Fraction.limit_denominator):

> Finds and returns the closest `Fraction` to `self` that has denominator at most max_denominator. This method is useful for finding rational approximations to a given floating-point number

Floating point numbers are limited in precision and cannot represent many numbers *exactly*; what you see is a rounded representation, but the real number is:

```
>>> format(3.2, '.50f')
'3.20000000000000017763568394002504646778106689453125'
```

because a floating point number is represented as a sum of binary fractions; 1/5 can only be represented by adding up 1/8 + 1/16 + 1/128 + more binary fractions for increasing exponents of two.

Comment: Thanks, I know how to do it with `fractions` I didn't understand why

Comment: No point expanding my answer further - good solution to get a "sane" rep :)

Answer (score 5):

It's not 16/5 because `3.2` isn't 3.2 *exactly*... it's a floating point rough approximation of it... eg: `3.20000000000000017764`

Comment: But why `2.5` the same as `2.5` and `3.2` not the same?

Comment: @itdxer I think it's value is pretty stable for numbers with `.5` as a divisor. They can be represented exactly as you define them.

Comment: @itdxer because some numbers can be represented exactly and some can't... See the link that [FallenAngel provided](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2100490/floating-point-inaccuracy-examples)

Comment: Because you can display integers with binary (base 2) but displaying decimal part is hard because you may not exactly write a decimal number in binary (base 2). So programming languages tries to evaluate the value closest to your expected result.

Answer (score 3):

While using the fractions module, it is better to provide a string instead of a float to avoid floating point representation issues.

For example, if you pass `'3.2'` instead of `3.2` you get your desired result:

```
In : fractions.Fraction('3.2')
Out: Fraction(16, 5)
```

If you already have the value stored in a variable, you can use string formatting as well.

```
In : value = 3.2

In : fractions.Fraction(f'{value:.2f}')
Out: Fraction(16, 5)
```